# Html Unknown border around h3?

Tags: html, css

**Why is there border showing up around H3 in the red div, also on the slider div ?
I could not find any border code in the css.**

More text so i can submit the question

**Why is there border showing up around H3 in the red div, also on the slider div ?
I could not find any border code in the css.**

Please help**Why is there border showing up around H3 in the red div, also on the slider div ?
I could not find any border code in the css.**

Please help

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.clearfix{ clear:both;}

body{ 
 
  
  }

@font-face {font-family: Orator Std;
 src: url(fonts/OratorStd.otf);}
 
 
 
@font-face {font-family: Century Gothic;
 src: url(fonts/GOTHIC.TTF);} 

.wrapper{ width:100%; 
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
   background-image: 
  
  overflow:hidden;
        }
.header{ width:100%;
  height:240;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: 
    
       }
    
.bannerbox    {width:100%;
   height:150px;
   padding-top:50px;
   
   ; background-color:#FFF;
   
   
   }

.bannercntr{ 
   font-family: "Orator Std";
           }
     
     
.bannergothic{font-family:"Century Gothic";
    border: none;}     
     
.blockimgs{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
           }

.megablock{width:1000px;
   height:500px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   }

      
.blockimgsw1{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image:url(Images/australia.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw1:hover { background-image: url(Images/australia%20-%20Copy.fw.png)}


.blockimgsw2{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image: url(Images/Canada.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw2:hover { background-image: url(Images/Canada%20-%20Copy.fw.png)}


.blockimgsw3{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image: url(Images/china.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw3:hover { background-image: url(Images/china%20-%20Copy.fw.png)}

.blockimgsw4{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image: url(Images/dubai.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw4:hover { background-image: url(Images/dubai%20-%20Copy.fw.png)}


.blockimgsw5{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image: url(Images/europe.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw5:hover { background-image: url(Images/europe%20-%20Copy.fw.png)}

.blockimgsw6{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image: url(Images/singapore.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw6:hover { background-image: url(Images/singapore%20-%20Copy.fw.png) }


.blockimgsw7{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image:url(Images/southAfrica.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw7:hover { background-image: url(Images/southAfrica%20-%20Copy.fw.png)}


.blockimgsw8{height:250px;
    width:250px;
   float:left;
   background-image: url(Images/USA.jpg)
           }    
.blockimgsw8:hover { background-image: url(Images/USA%20-%20Copy.fw.png)}

.ddmenubox{width:700px;
   float:right;
           }
.logodiv{float:left;}


<!-----Drop Down Menu---->


ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000;z-index:1}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}

<!----Drop Down Menu END--->





.rightheader{float:right;
    height:240px;
    width:500px;}

.horilist{ float:left;
    list-style:none;
 font-family:"Century Gothic";
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:800;
 padding-right:20px;
 margin:0px auto;
 }
 
.subbox {width:1000px;
         height:280px;
   padding-top:20px;
   background-image:url(Images/matte-red.jpg);
   background-repeat:repeat;
  
   overflow:hidden;
        }


<!-----SLIDER---->

.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto;  }
    .banner li { list-style: none; height:400px;}
        .banner ul li { float: left; }

<!-----SLIDER--END---->
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Travel the World</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">



<!-----Slider----->



 <!-----Slider  end---->


</head>




<body>

<div class="header"> <div class="logodiv"> <img src="Images/One.png">  </div>

 <div class="ddmenubox">

<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

 </div>


</div>



<div class="wrapper">
<!---Insert Slider----> 
  
        <div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-image:url(Images/002.jpg)">This is a slide.</li>
        <li>This is another slide.</li>
        <li>This is a final slide.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
        

  
<!------SLIDER AREA END---->    
    
    <div class="bannerbox">
    <center>
   
   <h3 class="bannergothic">You can simple dream a great vacation. But it is a tough job to make it into a reality and to find <br>a travel company who delightfully crafts your trip. <br>At One World Holidayz we make it our pleasure to transform your dream holiday into a reality.</h3>
   
    </center>
    </div>
    
    <div class="megablock">
    <div class="blockimgsw1">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockimgsw2">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockimgsw3">
    
    </div>
   
    <div class="blockimgsw4">
   
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockimgsw5">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockimgsw6">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockimgsw7">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockimgsw8">
   
    </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
  <div class="bannerbox">
    <center>
   <h2 class="bannercntr"> ADVENTURE IS EVERYWHERE </h2>
   <h3 class="bannergothic"> You can simple dream a great vacation. But it is a tough job to make it into a reality and to find a travel company who delightfully crafts your trip. At One World Holidayz we make it our pleasure to transform your dream holiday into a reality.</h3>
   
    </center>
    </div>


 <div class="subbox">
    <ul class="horilist">
    <li class="horilist">
    China
    </li>
    <li class="horilist">
    Australia
    </li>
    <li class="horilist">
    Canada
    </li>
    
    <li class="horilist">
    Dubai
    </li>
    
    <li class="horilist">
    New Zealand
    </li>
    
    <li class="horilist">
    Europe
    </li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul>
    <li class="horilist">
    Hong Kong
    </li>
    
    <li class="horilist">
    Asia
    </li>
    
      
    
    <li class="horilist">
    USA
    </li>
    
    <li class="horilist">
    South Africa
    </li>
    
    <li class="horilist">
    United Kingdom
    </li>
    
    
    </ul>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
</div>






<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.banner').unslider();
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually browser developer tools are pretty helpful to inspect calculated style...and to see where each one comes from. Can I kindly suggest to start/learn to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your

```
ul li{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Which the border 1px make your slider to hold the border. So just remove the border or just make em `0` and you are good to go with your slider with no border.

Comment: You are welcome but don't miss the comment of @AdrianoRepetti